# Looping in a spiral outside-in, to populate it by a counter, incrementally

Tags: algorithm, spiral

In this question: [Looping in a spiral outside-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837273/looping-in-a-spiral-outside-in), there is a way to "extract the values spirally in a matrix".  But what if the requirement is, given an **empty** n × m matrix, populate it so that it looks something like:

```
[
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4,],
  [12,13,14, 5,],
  [11,16,15, 6,],
  [10, 9, 8, 7,]
]
```

(so the above is matrix is, given a 4 × 4 matrix, with all `0`s in it, and now populate this matrix so that it looks like the above matrix.  Then is there a way like the recursive answer as in [Looping in a spiral outside-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837273/looping-in-a-spiral-outside-in) ?  (Although my concern also is: that solution is elegant, but it is not `O(n*m)`)

Comment: Hope it helps: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Spiral_matrix

Comment: see [Print 2-D Array in clockwise expanding spiral from center](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33688562/2521214) just use/generate the turtle command string in reverse

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly elegant, but it's easy to keep track of the next four coordinates where you'll turn (i.e., start placing elements in a different direction) and to cycle through the four directions. Each time you come to a turn, you replace it with the coordinate 1 towards the center of the matrix on both axes (which is where your next turn for that corner will be) and switch to the next direction.